# Which article should be used in this sentence?

Tags: articles

Since I have specified where the change happened - the ecosystem, should I use article "the" here?
Also, should I put "the" before ecosystem?

> The extinction of endangered animals results in **the** dramatic changes in **ecosystems** and in the food chain

Answer (score 1):

The first article is unnecessary, since "changes" is plural, but is needed in the singular "food chain". If one is picky, it might be better to use parallel construction and have them *both* plural: if there are isolated ecosystems, then there would be multiple food chains. In that case, no article is needed there, either.

Comment: u mean when the noun after preposition of is plural, we do not need to use definite article for the noun in front of?

Comment: Actually, it should have referenced "changes"... that is being corrected. Sorry.

Comment: Outside of a more compelling context, I don't think the definite article at the beginning of the sentence is needed either. What do you think?

Comment: Agreed, the initial "The" is optional.

Comment: so normally, if we talk about general concept, we would use either the +singular noun or plural nouns only?

Comment: Thanks. @GoodieGood Not really. You'd normally use either plural nouns or singular nouns preceded by an indefinite article. See [this dissertation](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/IV-GenericNPs.pdf) or [this summary](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), however, if you're really interested in the topic.